# Why is Graphic Design still Beta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The area 51 suggests that sites need to stay in beta for 90 days at least, to build up users.

At present, Graphic Design is running at 943 days in beta (at the time of posting).
When is it going to launch officially?

Comment: I've been wondering about this. [Months ago we were told](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/404/) that there was a plan in place to help us over whatever the last hurdles to launching were, which included getting a proper site design so we would actually look like a real legit graphic design site, and that we'd be kept updated every step of the way. Then we improved our stats quite a lot, but heard nothing more [apparently because the one member of staff involved in this moved on and none of the work got picked up](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/580/3327).

Comment: Stats-wise [our site performs well](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/541/improving-our-answer-ratio-or-one-step-closer-to-an-all-green-area51-page), and even on the one thing we're not so good on - [questions per day - usually beats 6-10 launched sites and is consistently one of the top non-code beta sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). That's with the handicap of trying to appeal to designers while not *looking* like a legit design site. I don't know what's going on - I think there was one guy advocating for us, then he left, then we got forgotten about

Comment: I've been on this site, pretty much since it's inception. I'm not overtly active on it (more so on Stack Overflow), but occasionally I need it, and I was curious why it's had pretty much the same design since I joined (aside from that horrible graph-paper style that originally represented Beta sites). I was struck by the fact that it still says `beta` on it. May be doing us more harm than good!

Comment: **Beta no more!**

Comment: I added the **feature request** tag to this question so it gets bumped to SE. I've just finished [**a meta post with some of the changes we've been (successfully) implementing in the last couple of months**](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/638/what-we-have-been-up-to-bi-monthly-report-from-the-strike-team), I think it will be encouraging for everyone!

Answer (score 24):

**Graphic Design will graduate**... as soon as our designer Jin can get the new skin together. It's currently in line behind two other soon-to-graduate sites.

I hadn't mentioned it because it still could be a while yet - Jin is only human! - and we didn't want to get anyone's hopes up. But, since you asked... The Community Team can see that the site is in great shape, and in mid-June we decided to graduate it. Now, all that remains is to keep up the good work while we wait for the design.

Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks for this! Very helpful!

Comment: ___ :-D ___ Yay!

Comment: Woooooohoooooo! :D

Comment: What's the latest on this... Obviously, this was posted a couple of months ago now.

Comment: Any updates on this? How are we doing on our daily stats?

Comment: No change. Still looking good, still in line. The bottleneck's in the design phase. Stay tuned!

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller - Thanks for the update!